# SqlBulkCopy prevent insert data that null or not in relationship table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I using to extract data from excel and put in sql table as below:

```
public bool ExtractExcelToDB(int activityId, string tableName, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var path = GetPath(activityId);
        path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
            {
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                DataTable dt = result.Tables["sheet"];
                DataTable newDt = dt.Select().Skip(1).Take(dt.Rows.Count).CopyToDataTable();

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(newDt);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my relationship:

[image]

My issue is that the table that I insert the data has primary key and the data **insert to table even the primary key is null or does not exist in the relationship table**

> How to prevent the data to insert to target table if on of the primary
>   key is null or doesn't exist..

Answer (score 1):

Using the constructor [SqlBulkCopy(String, SqlBulkCopyOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopyOptions_) set the [options](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=netframework-4.8) to check the constraints while performing the insert:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))
{
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(newDt);
}
```

by default the constraints are not checked.

Comment: Try to set `KeepNulls` too: `new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls)`

Comment: `KeepNulls` is only to primary key or to all fields? (Because I have some columns that can be null)

Comment: Should be for all fields

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your Authority table in the same manner you could check the ID values manually as well as follows:

```
public bool ExtractExcelToDB(int activityId, string tableName, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var path = GetPath(activityId);
        path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
            {
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                DataTable dt = result.Tables["sheet"];

                // EDIT: Perhaps you can get access the "Authority Table" here as well? e.g.
                DataTable AuthorityTable = result.Tables["AuthoritySheet"];

                // I'll try to do something equivalent
                //DataTable newDt = dt.Select().Skip(1).Take(dt.Rows.Count).CopyToDataTable();
                DataTable newDt = dt.Clone();
                bool firstRow = true;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["Id"] != null && !firstRow && AuthorityContainsKey(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]), AuthorityTable))
                        newDt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    else
                        firstRow = false;
                }

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(newDt);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

public bool AuthorityContainsKey(int id, DataTable Auth)
{
    bool result = false;

    foreach (DataRow dr in Auth.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["Id"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]) == id)
            return true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: that only for null case **not** for relationship case

Comment: I've added something that could work; assuming you have the Authority table in one of the sheets as well, would this suffice?

Comment: Assuming you have that table as well - it would be better / faster to e.g. create a list of all your "valid" IDs first - instead of searching the Authority table every time.